# I want to paste a copied cell block from Excel into a chart's data in a PPT presentation using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I am writing a macro through Excel that will help me do the steps below. Currently, I am stuck at step 3.

1. 'Copy specific cellblock in Excel sheet
2. 'Open existing Powerpoint presentation (which exists of four slides with approximately 6-7 charts on each slides whose underlying data has to be replaced with the copied cellblock)
3. 'Select specific chart on slide 1
4. 'Open the specific chart's underlying data by right clicking on "Edit Data"
5. Select the cellblock in the sheet that pops up and replace it with the data that was copied from Excel in step 1

My issue at the moment lies in step 3, where I am not able to select any chart in my PowerPoint. I would also appreciate all guidance that could help me with step 4 and 5 as well.

**My current code looks as the following:**

```
Sub MyMacroRätt()

'Marks and copies a cell block in my Excel file 

    ActiveSheet.Range("R55", "T75").Select
    Selection.Copy

'Open an existing PowerPoint file 

        Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
        Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
        PPT.Visible = True
        PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Users\seleveafe\Desktop\XXXXXX.pptm"

        Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
        Set PPPres = PPT.ActivePresentation
        Dim pslide As PowerPoint.Slide
        Dim pchart As PowerPoint.Chart

'Mark the first chart on the first slide 
        With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

            If .HasChart = True Then

'Open Edit Data-sheet for selected chart 
        Chart.ActivateChartDataWindow

        End If
        End With

'Select existing data i Edit Data-sheet and replace with copied data from Excel 

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you explain more of what you mean by "not able to select"?  What have you tried and what is it doing? (For example, are you getting an error?)

Answer (score 0):

The following macro opens the specified PowerPoint file, activates the ChartData so that its workbook is opened, copies the specified data into the first worksheet of the workbook, starting at A2, and then closes it.  You'll need to change the destination cell (A2) accordingly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacroRätt()

    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim rngCopyFrom As Range

    Set rngCopyFrom = ActiveSheet.Range("R55", "T75")

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    pptApp.Visible = True

    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\seleveafe\Desktop\XXXXXX.pptm")

    With pptPres.Slides(1) 'first slide
        For Each pptShape In .Shapes
            If pptShape.HasChart Then 'first chart
                Exit For
            End If
        Next pptShape
        If Not pptShape Is Nothing Then
            pptShape.Chart.ChartData.Activate
            With rngCopyFrom
                pptShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a2") _
                    .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
            pptShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Close
        End If
    End With

    Set pptApp = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptShape = Nothing
    Set rngCopyFrom = Nothing

End Sub
```

***Edit***

To choose which chart to update, for example the second chart, try the following instead...

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacroRätt()

    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim rngCopyFrom As Range
    Dim ChartNum As Long
    Dim ChartIndex As Long

    ChartNum = 2 'second chart

    Set rngCopyFrom = ActiveSheet.Range("R55", "T75")

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    pptApp.Visible = True

    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\seleveafe\Desktop\XXXXXX.pptm")

    With pptPres.Slides(1) 'first slide
        ChartIndex = 0
        For Each pptShape In .Shapes
            If pptShape.HasChart Then
                ChartIndex = ChartIndex + 1
                If ChartIndex = ChartNum Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next pptShape
        If Not pptShape Is Nothing Then
            pptShape.Chart.ChartData.Activate
            With rngCopyFrom
                pptShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a2") _
                    .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
            pptShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Close
        End If
    End With

    Set pptApp = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptShape = Nothing
    Set rngCopyFrom = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Domenic, it actually worked! Now I want to repeat this again for more charts in my PPT, so in the first step "Set rngCopyFrom = ActiveSheet.Range("R55", "T75") I will change the cell block that should be copied from Excel. However, when I will repeat the whole code you sent I also want to change the selected chart into THE SECOND CHART on the first slide in the PPT. Do you have ideas on how I can adjust this section so that it instead selects the second chart in slide 1, and pastes the new cell block into that charts worksheet?   
            If pptShape.HasChart Then 'first chart

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Domenic, it actually worked!

Now I want to repeat this again for more charts in my PPT, so in the first step "Set rngCopyFrom = ActiveSheet.Range("R55", "T75") I will change the cell block that should be copied from Excel. However, when I will repeat the whole code you sent I also want to change the selected chart into THE SECOND CHART on the first slide in the PPT. Do you have ideas on how I can adjust this section so that it instead selects the second chart in slide 1, and pastes the new cell block into that charts worksheet?

```
        If pptShape.HasChart Then 'first chart
```

In other words, I want a code that selects the second chart on slide 1, another code that selects the third chart on slide 1, another code that selects the fourth chart on slide 1..... and so on. In total I have 8 charts on each slide, and in total I have four slides with charts whose data that needs to be updated.